# pass list as parameter to udf pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My json schema looks like this

```
 {
  "uid": "a7f2e98835c1fb67e9aa9f1fbaae5e98", 
  "gender": "F", 
  "click": [
    {
      "url": "htp://abc.com/1.html?utm_campaign=397"
    },
    {
      "url": "htp://qaz.com/1.html?utm_campaign=397"
    }
  ]
}
```

i have udf that clean **visits.url**, for example my_udf("htp://abc.com/1.html?utm_campaign=397") i get **abc.com**

I want to get dataframe with cleansed url:

```
uid                              gender    urls
a7f2e98835c1fb67e9aa9f1fbaae5e98 F         [abc.com,qaz.com]
```

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.request import urlretrieve, unquote

clean = F.udf (lambda z:my_udf(z), ArrayType(StringType())) 

def my_udf(url):
    url = re.sub('(http(s)*://)+', 'http://', url)
    parsed_url = urlparse(unquote(url.strip()))
    if parsed_url.scheme not in ['http','https']: return None
    netloc = re.search("(?:www\.)?(.*)", parsed_url.netloc).group(1)
    if netloc is not None: return str(netloc.encode('utf8')).strip()
    return None

dataFrame = spark.read.json('1.json') \
.withColumn("urls", clean(F.col("click.url"))) \
.select( F.col("uid"), F.col("gender"), F.col("urls") ) \
show(3)
```

But i get errors:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: your definition of the udf is problematic - you don't need `lambda`. Also can you show the source code for `my_udf` as well?

Comment: added code of my_udf

Comment: try `clean = F.udf (my_udf, ArrayType(StringType())) `

Answer (score 0):

i did it:

```
dataFrame = spark.read.json('1.json') \
    .withColumn("urls_exploded",  F.explode(  F.col("click.url") )) \
    .withColumn("urls_cleaned", my_udf(F.col("urls_exploded"))) \
    .groupBy(F.col("uid"),F.col("gender") ) \
    .agg(F.collect_set(F.col("urls_cleaned")).alias("urls") ) \
    .select( F.col("uid"), F.col("gender_age"), F.col("urls") ) \
    .show(1,truncate=False)
```